# React Native IBM Mobile First - WLAuthorizationManager.login() Returns Bad Request 400 in IOS

Tags: react-native, ibm-mobilefirst, react-native-ios

We integrated react-native-ibm-mobilefirst version 8.0.2020032412 in our app. Everything works fine and here's our code for login:

```
WLAuthorizationManager.login(SECURITY_NAME, { 'username': username, 'password': password, rememberMe: false })
```

Until we upgraded react-native from 0.61.5 to 0.63:

- Android - returns success
- iOS - returns bad request

  ```
   "code":"Error Domain=WL_AUTH Code=400 \"Request failed: bad request (400)\"
  ```

What I tried so far:

- JSON.stringify the credentials object
- updated mobile first
- reverted mobile first to old version

But result is still the same.

Has anyone experienced this before? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you see this issue, 
i. if you uninstall and reinstall the app OR ii.delete the app on device from mfp console and reregister the app ?

Comment: Tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app on the device and issue still happens only in IOS.. Android is OK. Unregistering from mfp, I never tried because it's out of our control for some reason

Comment: Please update the question with logs from your Mobile Foundation server

Comment: any updates. were u able to install an older verison? how?